# Are usernames required to be unique?

Tags: discussion, reputation, display-names

I recently changed my username to Undo. I was amazed when I pressed Submit and saw that it actually went through - surely someone somewhere was using this same username.

Out of curiosity, I then search the SO user list for Undo - and found [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706528/undo) with Undo as thier name. They have 50 rep. I have around 1,500.

Is there some kind of pecking order, I.e. a high-rep user can 'steal' a low-rep user's name? Or is this a bug?

Or can two users have the same username without causing the SO servers to go down in a burning ring of fire?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Accounts aren't tied to display names, they aren't required to be unique. However, if you participate in comments or chat with someone that has the same display name, you'll get a bit of noise in your global inbox if someone mentions one of you.

What you can't do is [impersonate someone else](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), or otherwise harass people:

> Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service
> to (a) send unsolicited e-mails, bulk mail, spam or other materials to
> users of the Network or any other individual, (b) harass, threaten,
> stalk or abuse any person or party, including other users of the
> Network, (c) create a false identity or to impersonate another person,
> or (d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material.

There's a difference between sharing the same name as another user, and pretending to *be* another user.

Barring that, there's no issue if several or more people share the same display name.

Answer (score 10):

They're not *usernames*; they're *display names*. There's a big difference. A *username* is generally a unique string that identifies a user in the system. Stack Exchange doesn't use those; they use OpenID providers and a simple ID number. Your *display name* is merely an alternate string that more accurately represents who you are, and are *rarely ever* unique. They usually allow users to utilize a wider variety of characters, as well.

Answer (score 4):

Usernames are not required to be unique.

[image]

Comment: Just wondering why you used `mike` as a test case instead of `adam` or `undo` =)

Comment: @hjp - meh - Mike seemed like the ideally common name at the moment :)

Comment: As of now, [`Mike` is #4 behind `John`, `Chris`, `Alex`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/108420)